# How to load a json file based on locale of the browser in angular1.x?

Tags: date-format, setlocale, angular-date-format

In my project the selection of browser locale I want to change the date format, how can I get the date format according to the locale in javascript or angularjs

Comment: I helped me to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

in order to detect user time format you can use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

after including moment.js library, first detect user locale by this javascript code :

`let user_locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;`

then feed the user_locale value to `moment.locale();` function like this

`moment.locale(user_locale);`

after declaring localData

`let localeData = moment.localeData()`

you can use LongDateFormat

`localeData.longDateFormat(dateFormat);  // returns the full format of abbreviated date-time formats LT, L, LL and so on`

to get time format.